# Python: scipy's optimize functions do not work/give dimension errors

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, scipy, dimensions

I am implementing Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on Python, but I got stuck because the scipy's optimize functions keep giving me a hard time by not working/giving me dimension errors

The goal is to find the minimum of the cost function (a scalar function that takes `theta (dimension (1,401))`, `X (dimension (5000,401))`, and y `(dimension (5000,1))` as inputs). I have defined such cost function and its gradient wrt parameters. When running one of the optimize functions (I have tried `fmin_tnc`, `minimize`, `Nelder-Mead` and others, all not working), either they run for ages or keep giving me errors saying that the array dimension is wrong, or that they find a division by 0... errors that I am not able to spot.
weirdest thing is that this problem has popped up at first when I was doing exercise 2 on logistic regression, and then magically disappeared without me changing anything. Now, Implementing multi-classification logistic regression, it has appeared again, and it won't fix even though I have literally copied and pasted the code of exercise 2!

The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import loadmat
import scipy.misc 
import matplotlib.cm as cm 
from scipy.optimize import minimize,fmin_tnc
import random

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def J(theta,X,y):
    theta_t=np.transpose(theta)
    prod=np.matmul(X,theta_t)
    sigm=sigmoid(prod)
    vec=y*np.log(sigm)+(1-y)*np.log(1-sigm)
    return -np.sum(vec)/len(y)

def grad(theta,X,y):
    theta_t=np.transpose(theta)
    prod=np.matmul(X,theta_t)
    sigm=sigmoid(prod)
    one=sigm-y
    return np.matmul(np.transpose(one),X)/len(y)


data=loadmat('/home/marco/Desktop/MLang/mlex3/ex3/ex3data1.mat')

X,y = data['X'],data['y']

X=np.column_stack((np.ones(len(X[:,0])),X))

initial_theta=np.zeros((1,len(X[0,:])))
res=fmin_tnc(func=J, x0=initial_theta.flatten(), args=(X,y.flatten()), fprime=grad)
theta_opt=res[0]
```

Instead of returning the value of theta that minimizes the function as theta_opt, it says:

```
/home/marco/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages ipykernel_launcher.py:8: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
```

I have no clue where this divide by zero occurs, given that there is literally no division in the whole code, except for the division by `len(y)`, which is `5000`, and the division in the `sigmoid` function `(1/(1+exp(-z))`, which can never be `0`!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post some sample data?! Otherwise it is hard to help.

Comment: Sure, use this link to download the data --> https://s3.amazonaws.com/spark-public/ml/exercises/on-demand/machine-learning-ex3.zip